# Can I add a 11-40 XT or XTR rear cog to a road bike with Di2?

Tags: road-bike, cassette, compatibility, shimano-di2

I want to build up a road bike for the Baa Baa Bikepack and want some more large toothed gears. I want to run Di2 with a compact front derailleur and largest toothed cog possible. Ultegra CS-6800 is 11-32, but I'd like to run  XT CS-M8000 (11-40) or XTR CS-M9000. Is this possible on a road bike?

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Not answering because I haven't delved into this firsthand, but at present the consensus from internet articles is that Shimano intentionally blocked the ability to simultaneously run a road FD and a mountain RD. So basically your options are use a mountain FD and ring sizes it plays nice with, or 1x, or Di2/cable mashup, or something like a Wolftooth Roadlink to go up to 36t. Hacks to make it work the way we all want are probably technically possible which means they'll hopefully be a reality sooner or later, but I haven't seen any yet.

Comment: Thanks. With a Wolftooth I would take out one of the middle cogs, like a 17 - is that correct?

Comment: No, the Road Link and similar gizmos just drop the derailer down to clear a larger cog.

Comment: I know someone who uses Dura ace di2 with an 11-40 cassette by using a Roadlink. Not possible according to the textbook, but apparently works.

Answer (score 1):

I see some potential issues, but can only answer to some of them:

1. Rear derailleur maximum cog capacity. RD-6870 supports up to 32 teeth, so you'll have to get RD-M8050 or RD-M9050 for anything bigger than that.
2. Road/MTB DI2 capability. According [to this article](http://www.velonews.com/2014/12/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/tech-faq-mixing-shimano-road-mtb-derailleurs_356751), 6870 and M-8070/9070 should be compatible.
3. Rear derailleur overall capacity. I'm not sure how 8070/9070 will handle road double up front.
4. Freehub body width. Shimano 11-speed MTB cassettes are narrower than 11-speed Shimano road cassettes by about 1mm. Make sure you've fitting a spacer.